# sfdisk strange behavior: total size of partitions greater than device size

Tags: partition, partition-table, sfdisk

I have a ssd(256 Gb), when I'm trying to part it:

```
sfdisk /dev/sda << EOF
2048,8388608,S
,104857600,L
,,E
,20971520,L
,20971520,L
,20971520,L
,,L
EOF
fi
```

the output is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors

Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdedcd8ac

Device    Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size    Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    8390655    8388608  4G      82 Linux swap
/dev/sda2         8390656  113248255  104857600  50G     83 Linux
/dev/sda3       113248256  500118191  386869936  184.5G  5  Extended
/dev/sda5       113250304  134221823   20971520  10G     83 Linux
/dev/sda6       134223872  155195391   20971520  10G     83 Linux
/dev/sda7       155197440  176168959   20971520  10G     83 Linux
/dev/sda8       176171008  500118191  323947184  154.5G  83 Linux
```

How could it be? The total size of parts more than ssd size (423>256).

Comment: As pointed out in the [answer you have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510491/315749), extended partitions are containers for logical partitions, you can see them overlapping in the sector range 113248256-500118191. Also, note that 423 is the sum of partition sizes in GiB (gibibytes, 2^30 bytes), while 256 is the device size in GB (gigabytes, 2^9 bytes), so they are not directly comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition 3 is an extended partition and shows its size as sum of parts 5, 6, 7, 8.